# Postgres JSON function passed string instead of object

Tags: javascript, json, postgresql, stored-functions, jsonb

So I've got a Postgres function in place designed to merge two JSONB objects recursively, and it works just fine on the production server but fails on my local Postgres installation. The function itself is written in `plv8` (a v8 Javascript engine basically) and expects two arguments in JSONB format to merge; the problem is that the JSON is passed in as a string and not as an object, which essentially breaks the entire function.

This only happens on my local computer though, a fresh Postgres 9.4.5 installation. The production server is running 9.4.4, which shouldn't cause such a major change across versions...ideas on where to go to see what's broken here?

EDIT: Can now confirm that reverting to 9.4.4 doesn't make this behave any differently locally

Comment: install 9.4.4 locally and try?

Comment: You probably need an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org).

Comment: Can you cast the string inside your function as JSON or JSONB, then work from there? We won't know unless you post some code.

Comment: This is internal code so I'm waiting on confirmation about that I'm allowed to post... I can tell you that casting a JSON string to JSON/JSONB doesn't affect what gets passed into the function. No matter what the function itself gets a raw string.

Answer (score 0):

Hard to say. Possibilities:

1. Different casts - you can define custom casts - `CREATE CAST` statement - try to check result of `psql` command `\dC *json*`
2. New bug introduced in 9.4.5

Comment: No bug in 9.4.5 from what I can see; I also ran that command in `psql` and both servers give the same output so it doesn't look like that'd be the issue?

Answer (score 0):

FWIW, upgrading to 9.5 seems to solve instances of this issue for me.